# run nupichelloworld in pycharm

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, nupic

I want to run nupichelloworld (https://github.com/lonesword/nupichelloworld) within pycharm but can't figure out how to force it to see nupic libraries. All sources -- nupic.core, nupic.sources, nupichelloworld etc are located on the same level (/home) (I am using the NUPIC-03-11-2014 image which I took from
https://mega.co.nz). 
When I try to run it in console, that's all right, but pycharm tells following:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/nupic/nupichelloworld/helloworld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nupic/nupichelloworld/helloworld.py", line 22, in <module>
    import nupic
ImportError: No module named nupic
```

there is the such imports in the file:

```
from nupic.research.spatial_pooler import SpatialPooler as SP
import numpy as np
```

How to solve it? Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [configure the project's interpreter paths](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html) to include your package.